# iOS, JSON-RPC and NSJSONSerialization: Dealing with null values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, null, json-rpc, nsjsonserialization

I am using JSON-RPC to communicate between iOS application and the server. Some return values of the server are optional.

Considering the combination of technologies I am using, is it better to return these null values like {"telephone": null} or by completely omitting the "telephone" element in the response?

Futher explanation of what I am asking:

It doesn't look like the JSON-RPC spec specifies much to do with the method result (please correct me if I'm wrong) and clearly not sending loads null elements would improve performance and reduce bandwidth somewhat. What I'm most interested in though is the best approach from an iOS NSJSONSerialization perspective. Is it easier/better to check for whether a key exists in an NSDictionary or whether an existing key has a null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all {"telephone": "null"} is not a null value. There are quotes so actually telephone property has string value with text "null". Server needs to send {"telephone": null} - without quotes.
I'd go with listing all relevant properties that your app needs in response and put null as a value if there is not value. Then you can easily check in NSDictionary you get from NSJSONSerialization if value for key is NSNull.

```
if ([dictionaryValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    myThink.myProperty = nil;
```

Comment: Good spot. I've amended the question accordingly to use null instead of "null"

Comment: This is the approach I've decided to take.

Comment: NSNull has only one instance, so it's faster to check `value == [NSNull null]`

Answer (score 11):

I'm using a completely different technique, somewhat unorthodox for sure, since my code is dealing with huge data sets and I really hate having to make tests for NSNull on each value. What I did was subclass NSNull, so when dealing with data, I can test if its numeric value is 0, if its string length is 0, etc.

```
@implementation NSNull (JSON)

- (NSUInteger)length { return 0; }

- (NSInteger)integerValue { return 0; };

- (CGFloat)floatValue { return 0; };

- (NSString *)description { return @"0(null)"; } // so I know it was NSNull in log messages

- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator { return @[]; }

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key { return nil; }

- (BOOL)boolValue { return NO; }

@end
```

EDIT: I used this exact same code in an e-commerce shipping app. There were literally thousands of objects getting returned by tens of different APIs - having to look at each item to see if it was `[NSNull null]` would have been a nightmare. I tried to write a routine to groom results, it would recursively look at dictionaries and arrays and reconstruct the object, but it got too complicated.

In any case, I never even once had an issue with this solution. Obviously YMMV.

Comment: Interesting approach. And I assume you are suggesting I return {"telephone": null} as opposed to nothing?

Comment: In my case I don't own the web side of things. That said, you never know who else might use your web side code, so I personally would use a "standard" approach and not tune it for iOS - so yes, I'd use null - but on the iOS side it wouldn't make a difference since the subclass returns "" or 0 or whatever. In my iOS code, for a phone number, if its not 9 digits its not usable/complete, so I'd require the user to enter a new number in any case.

Comment: I chose not to go with this approach as I'm a bit hesitant to alter the behaviour of NSNull like this.

Comment: INT_MIN or INT_MAX might, however, be better default values.

Comment: @EsbenBjerregaard see EDIT above. Min and max values would not be appropriate - the null simply means "not there or undefined", and so 'inventory = null' was the same to my app as 'inventory = 0', the first meaning (perhaps) that the object was not yet stocked so inventory is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I've packed the check in a function, if anyone interested.

```
-(id)checkNull:(id)object{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])return nil;
    else return object;
}
```